# Specifying Notepad as OLE object

Tags: c#, com

For word application, we have `Word.Application` as program identifier. What is the program identifier for Notepad and Calculator?

Comment: what good use can you make of notepad/calculator when its invoked by other programs?

Comment: It means someone thinks this question is of low value to the community, or that you haven't performed enough research on your own, first, or that it's an unclear question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Word.Application` is the name of the a COM object which forms part of the Word API.

Notepad is a simple application which does not have a COM API. If you just wish to start an instance of notepad, then locate the `notepad.exe` file in `%WINDIR%` or `%WINDIR%\System32` (for W2k8), and start it as a new process from your application.

The same applies for `calc.exe`.

Comment: O.K this mean,s this is not possible!

Comment: @Zain: "This" *what* is not possible? What are you trying to do?